# Cascading Select Boxes with Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have two select boxes (counties and cities). When I change country I want to update the cities corresponding to countries.

Template:

```
<select id="countries">
  <% _(countries).each(function(country) { %>
    <option value="<%= country.id %>">`enter code here`<%= country.name %></option>
  <% }); %>
</select>
  <input id="countryId" name="countryId" type="hidden" value="<%= countryId %>" />
<select id="cities">
  <% _(cities[countryId]).each(function(city) { %>
    <option value="<%= city.id %>"><%= city.name %></option> 
  <% }); %>
</select>
```

View

```
 events: {          
    'change #countries': 'setCountry',
 },
 setCountry: function(element) {
   this.model.set('countryId', element.target.value);
   this.$el.find( "#countryId" ).val( this.model.get( "countryId" ) );     

   //this.render();             
 },
```

If I call the render() in the setCountry, it updates the cities, but it refreshes the other form elements like the validation messages.

How can I update the code, when I change the country it refresh only the cities selectbox?

Comment: Well, you could just use DOM manipulation to edit the options in the select when the country is changed, or you could turn the select into a subview of the main view and only re-render that particular subview instead of the entire view.  How would you rather handle it?

Comment: split template into 2 pieces, render only needed part.